# Solution tablesorter scroller widget caption

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, tablesorter

is there a parameter/option for tablesorter scroller widget to display
`<caption>` tags at the top of the Filter when using bootstrap?

[Caption looks not so good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQtZ1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are using tablesorter (fork) v2.25.5+...

There was a fix in v2.25.5 which fixes that exact caption issue (see [issue #1141](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1141)).